# What unicode character should I use to represent the fill bucket?

Tags: icon, html, fill, symbols, unicode

I'm designing a mockup paint editor for the web and I'm using unicode characters to represent all of the different tools. I ran into a problem when I got to the fill bucket - I can't find anything that would fit nicely. Is there a character that nicely represents the "fill" feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about something like this ▧?

I can't seem to make it larger so here's a pic

[image: Picture of a square white square with diagonal lines on it.]

Unicode number: U+2668 / HTML-code: `&#9639;`

Answer (score 2):

**If it can help, here's the whole list of unicodes with a nice big preview:**

http://unicode-table.com/en/.

Also, it could be helpful to know what unicodes you have used so far for the other tools!

---

**Some suggestions for the "bucket" and "fill" feature:**

⩂

[image]

```
Unicode number: U+2A42 / HTML-code: &#10818;
```

⩌

[image]

```
Unicode number: U+2A4C / HTML-code: &#10828;
```

⩏

[image]

```
Unicode number: U+2A4F / HTML-code: &#10831;
```

∐

[image]

```
Unicode number: U+2210 / HTML-code: &#8720;
```

∪

[image]

```
Unicode number: U+222A / HTML-code: &#8746;
```

⊍

[image]

```
Unicode number: U+228D / HTML-code: &#8845;
```

⊔

[image]

```
Unicode number: U+2294 / HTML-code: &#8852;
```

⋓

[image]

```
Unicode number: U+22D3 / HTML-code: &#8915;
```

◍

[image]

```
Unicode number: U+25CD / HTML-code: &#9677;
```

♨

[image]

```
Unicode number: U+2668 / HTML-code: &#9832;
```

Comment: wth is that last one supposed to be? A caravan on fire?

Comment: @PieBie haha! No it's my burning desire for a legacy version of the new Adobe CC interfaces  :/ Maybe we'll get unicodes icons too next time!

Comment: @PieBie it's a symbol for onsen: Japanese hot baths. It's come to mean 'bathing area' in general

Comment: I see where you're going with the 'bucket' aspect but I don't think any convey a sense of "fill".

Comment: @SaturnsEye Funny you say that because the symbol you suggested is quite similar to the circle with the lines I suggested! It was a bit hard to see until you edited your answer. I simply provided more examples since we have no idea what symbols are already used for the other tools.

Comment: Not saying the 'bucket' style symbols were bad, just didn't think you had one that I thought represented "fill" that much. I couldn't quite see the circle with lines so we was both on the right track I guess :)

Comment: While I like #2, I feel like I'd have to use text rotation combined with another character and purposely overlap the characters to make it seem like "fill". As for "◍".. I feel like "▧" is both prettier and gives the illusion of filling an entire canvas instead of just a circle region.